# Pug template inconsistent indentations problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

i am frustrated using pug template engine . it took my whole day but i didn't got anything. lot of trying it shows "inconsistent indentations" after that i got this result.  sometimes text goes into "our sponsor section" something it goes to "our mission section" depending on spaces and how i place them .i don't want to use it because I'm fed up.  what should i do now? in html method i don't have that kind of problem.  can i create a html and connect it to app.js . i don't know. what should i do now?
Please answer in details

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pug is frustrating, but you don't have to use it.
Assuming that you're using `express` (based on the question tags), there are a few "out-of-the-box" supported languages:
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

If you prefer something more like vanilla html, try Nunjucks.